# Is there a way to call a non-cloud function inside same file where the Firebase cloud functions were created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I still can't wrap my head around how these functions work generally. For the project, I created a function that will be called by whenever that function URL is called. Afterwards, the called function also uses a utility function. This function is used multiple times so I only find it sensible to create them in a separate function, although whenever I use the function after deployment, I get this error.

```
TypeError: this.isMM is not a function
    at exports.addOrder.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:130:11)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I only have a single file, `index.js` where I place all my functions, although I'm not sure why above function `isMM()` is not being read. Below is the relevant codeblock (I have replaced the content of the functions for simplicity's sake.

```
exports.addOrder = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var newValue = req.query.my_info;
  var anotherValue = req.query.another_info;

  var my_info = this.isMM(newValue);
  if(my_info){
    var another_info = this.isMM(anotherValue);
    if(another_info){
      doThis();
    }
  }
});

isMM = (toCheck) => {
  if(toCheck === 'someString'){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I wish to make isMM readable inside addOrder since this will be a reoccurring thing that I need to do for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do as follows and don't use `this` .

```
  var my_info = isMM(newValue);
  if(my_info){
    var another_info = isMM(anotherValue);
    if(another_info){
      doThis();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so accustomed to most ts code not working properly without the ```this``` notifier that it never occurred to me to try doing the code without it. The code is now finally working and the local functions are now being recognized!